# Mysql select N of X duplicates

Tags: mysql

Considering this table:

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | value  |
+-----+--------+
|  1  |   22   |
+-----+--------+
|  2  |   12   |
+-----+--------+
|  3  |   22   |
+-----+--------+
|  4  |   22   |
+-----+ -------+
```

I can select all where the column `value` is duplicated like so:

```
select value from table having count(value) > 1 ;
```

This will output the `Ids` 1,3 and 4.

What I'm attempting to do is select where duplicates, but leaving 1 (one) duplicate un selected, so the above would output only the `Ids` 3 and 4 (or 1 and 3 etc... the duplicate omitted does not matter, only that it is.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:  I'm not sure why this is marked as a duplicate, as I am asking how to omit a duplicated result, not how to limit or rank.

Comment: Doesn't matter which one is left unselected?

Comment: @Alfabravo: Doesn't matter, as long as it has a duplicated value.

Comment: The fact that "it doesn't matter" is often indicative of poor design. It *should* matter!!!

Comment: Wow, this is definitively not a duplicate of that question...